# Probability of exceedance and reliability of a sample range estimation

Tags: probability, confidence-interval, extreme-value

Consider that $P$ is the water pressure coming out of a valve $A$. Let $P_{dif}$ be the difference between the maximum and the minimum pressure of valve $A$:

$$P_{dif}≔P_{max}-P_{min}$$

Now, what I want to do is estimate $P_{dif}$. In order to do that, I take a number of water pressure samples from valve $A$.

Let $S$ be a set of $3$ measured samples:

$$S = {5,7,1}$$

That is, $S$ contains 3 random samples of $P$, therefore, by placing S in ascending order, I can estimate $P_{dif}$ like that:

$$\hat{P}_{dif} = S_{(n:3)}-S_{(n:1)} = 7-1 = 6$$

Questions:

- What is the probability of exceeding this estimation ($\hat{P}_{dif}$). That is, what is the probability that the population parameter ($P_{dif}$) will exceed the estimation ($\hat{P}_{dif}$).
- Reliability of the estimation ($\hat{P}_{dif}$): this refers to the probability that the estimation is wrong (it may be possible to find this by deriving the confidence interval of the sample range, but I don't know how).

Any help towards this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The population parameter is the greatest possible difference in water pressures that could be measured. Under many reasonable assumptions, it is virtually *certain* that the range in any finite set of measurements will be less than this value.  If you wish to derive a confidence interval, you need to supply additional assumptions about the distribution of water pressures.

Comment: @whuber: What sort of assumptions do I need to supply? Would it help if I add a figure of the water pressure samples (they are actually more than 3, however I've mentioned just 3 in the description to make it more readable)? Regarding the probability of exceedance, do you have any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: You need to make assumptions about the upper and lower tails of the distribution of water pressures (as well as assuming that the true range $P_{dif}$ is finite).

Comment: Do you suggest that I need to create a kernel density transformed representation from the measured $P$ values? If we assume that the range of $P_{dif}$ refers to a specific time interval (e.g. 1 year), and that we are interested in the water pressure **only** at the time of sampling, doesn't this make it finite? When you say that I need to make assumptions about the tails of the distribution, could you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting a KDE, because that means you are assuming the tails have the shape of the kernel. "Tails" is pretty specific: have a look at [extreme value theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory) and search the [tag:extreme-value] tag for relevant examples.